# Spring Boot / Spring Data / Hibernate / JPA Dynamically generating select statement based on columns sent from frontend

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I'm currently facing a unique scenario that I have been unable to successfully find an answer to that doesn't involve creating a custom repository implementation.

Currently I have an entity that maps to a table and has around 20 fields. These fields are read from the entity and sent to the user who can then select them in a list and send it back to the server. This is where I encounter the problem. From what it seems there is no way to pass in parameters to the select statement of a Spring Data query. A solution could be to change it to a nativeQuery and then build my own select string. The problem with this solution is that by switching it to a native query I am going to lose out on paging and being able to apply a predicate that is built with QueryDSL for the where clause. I am unsure what the best way forward is

**Example**:

Foo with fields: A, B, C, D, E, F, G

A user request to only be given a result for fields A and E

```
@Query("SELECT :selectString FROM FOO foo")
Page<Foo> getFoo(Predicate predicate, Pageable page, Bar selectString)
```

This would be ideal, however hibernate doesn't allow passing a parameter into the select clause unless you are inserting.

So to try to avoid this I saw that [QueryDSL allows passing in literals](http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/5.0.0/reference/html_single/#d0e1287) so I tried that route.

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;

JPAQueryFactory factory = new JPAQueryFactory(entityManager);
QFoo foo = QFoo.foo;
FooPredicate predicate = new FooPredicate();
factory.select(Expressions.constant("A")).from(foo).where(predicate).fetch();
```

But it ran into the same problem of not allowing select parameters into the select clause.

Comment: Please don't do this, this is begging for SQL injection vulnerabilities. Parse the request body / parameters and build the query programmatically.

Comment: I am aware this is not ideal. I can just reflect through the entity's decalred fields and make sure the fields from the frontend exist on the entity and are an exact match, if not discard them from the selected.

Comment: In that case you can probably pass the path string to the PathBuilder to create the Path expression in Querydsl.